# Ext JS Tab Panel - Dynamic Tabs - Tab Exists Not Working

Tags: extjs

Would appreciate if somebody could help me on this.

I have a `treepanel` whose nodes when clicked load a tab into a `tabpanel`.

The tabs are loading alright, but my problem is duplication. I need to check if a tab exists before adding it to the tab panel. I cant seem to have this resolved and it is eating my brains. This is pretty simple and I have checked stackoverflow and the EXT JS Forums for solutions but they dont seem to work for me or I'm being blind.

This is my code for the tree:

```
var opstree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel({
    renderTo: 'opstree',
    border: false,
    width: 250,
    height: 'auto',
    useArrows: false,
    animate: true,
    autoScroll: true,
    dataUrl: 'libs/tree-data.json',
    root: {
        nodeType: 'async',
        text: 'Tool Actions'
    },
    listeners: {
        render: function() {
            this.getRootNode().expand();
        }
    }
});

opstree.on('click', function(n) {
    var sn = this.selModel.selNode || {}; // selNode is null on initial selection
    renderPage(n.id);
});

function renderPage(tabId) {

    var TabPanel = Ext.getCmp('content-tab-panel');
    var tab = TabPanel.getItem(tabId);

    //Ext.MessageBox.alert('TabGet',tab);

    if (tab) {
        TabPanel.setActiveTab(tabId);
    } else {
        TabPanel.add({
            title: tabId,
            html: 'Tab Body ' + (tabId) + '<br/><br/>',
            closable: true
        }).show();

        TabPanel.doLayout();
    }
}
```

And this is the code for the `tabpanel`:

```
new Ext.TabPanel({
    id: 'content-tab-panel',
    region: 'center',
    deferredRender: false,
    enableTabScroll: true,
    activeTab: 0,

    items: [{
        contentEl: 'about',
        title: 'About the Billing Ops Application',
        closable: true,
        autoScroll: true,
        margins: '0 0 0 0'
    }, {
        contentEl: 'welcomescreen',
        title: 'PBRT Application Home',
        closable: false,
        autoScroll: true,
        margins: '0 0 0 0'
    }]
});
```

Can somebody please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to doing this is to build a consistent naming convention for your tabs, so you can reliably know if that tab has been added yet. It looks like you've chosen to use the node's id - which is fine. When you call `TabPanel.add`, send the node's id as the new tab's `id`. Then  you can test to see if it exists with `TabPanel.findById`.

*Note:* some of your variable names are pretty confusing. `TabPanel` is a poor choice for a variable name, keep them beginning with lower case and never name them after the framework classes. Try `tabs` or `tp`. Also, the naming convention will be clearer if you prefix the node id with a string like `tab-`. Adding a new tab could also be encapsulated into a custom method on your tab panel, if you extend it.

Comment: I was being blind there. I thought I added the node id as the created tab's id but I didn't. Thanks for pointing that out Jonathan. It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

There has been some modifications on the Extjs API **.findById()** doesn't work, to implement this in ExtJs 4.0 try this

```
function AddTabs(tabTitle,yourTabId){
    var YourTabPanel = Ext.getCmp('YourTabPanelId');
    var TabToCheck = YourTabPanel.getChildByElement(yourTabId);
    if(TabToCheck){
       YourTabPanel.setActiveTab(yourTabId);
    } else {
    YourTabPanel .add({
        title:tabTitle,
        id:nId,
        closable:true,
        autoScroll:true,
        layout: 'fit',
        }).show();
  }
  YourTabPanel.doLayout();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the function `renderPage(tabId)` with the following:

```
function renderPage(tabId) {

    var TabPanel = Ext.getCmp('content-tab-panel');
    var tab = TabPanel.getItem(tabId);

    //Ext.MessageBox.alert('TabGet',tab);

    if(tab){
     TabPanel.setActiveTab(tabId);
    }
    else{
     TabPanel.add({
     title: tabId,
     html: 'Tab Body ' + (tabId) + '
',    
     id: tabId,**// this line very important, without this its not working**  
     closable:true
     }).show(); 

     TabPanel.doLayout();
    }    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addNewTab(nName,nId){
    //nName is Node Name and nId is node Id
    //Ext.Msg.alert('message',nId);
    var tp = Ext.getCmp('content-tab-panel');//Tab Panel Id
    var checkTab=tp.findById(nId);
    if(checkTab){
        tp.setActiveTab(nId);
    } else {
        tp.add({
            title:nName,
            id:nId,
            closable:true,
            autoScroll:true
            }).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you add some text to explain your code snippet? :)

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but I think this would work.

```
if (!Ext.getCmp('content-tab-panel')) {
    Tabpanel.add({ config }).show();
    Tabpanel.doLayout();
}
```

Comment: This adds a tab if the Ext.TabPanel does not exist. But it will always exist - you need to check for existence of the specific tab, not the entire panel.

Comment: Oh, true.  That's what I get for posting early in the morning. :)

Comment: ;-) Thanks Guys. I am pretty new to Ext Js. Getting the hang of it!